# get paragraph below the heading from anywhere

Tags: html

I am not getting how to get any specific paragraph after the heading.

Following is my `HTML` file script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>SAM.com</title>
</head>
<body><h1>This is Heading</h1>
      <p>This is paragraph 1</p>

      <p>This is paragraph 2</p>

      <p>This is paragraph 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I want to display paragraph 3 after the heading at the first level.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit better what's the issue here?

Comment: get paragraph below the selected heading from anywhere in a HTML Script

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a CSS solution, you can use a flexbox layout with the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property set:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  order: 1;
}

p:nth-child(4) {
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is Heading</h1>

<p>This is paragraph 1</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2</p>
<p>This is paragraph 3</p>
```

---

If you're looking for a JavaScript solution, some basic DOM manipulation methods like [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) will also do the trick:

```js
document.body.insertBefore(
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[2],
  document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].nextSibling
);
```

```html
<h1>This is Heading</h1>

<p>This is paragraph 1</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2</p>
<p>This is paragraph 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use "table" or "div" tag to meet your requirement instead of "p" tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position:absolute` for the paragraph you want to position and position it any way you want it, if you want to position any where in the script, or you could also use Robby's method as well.

Here are some links to help you

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp